# Determine cluster directory from Postgres service

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to determine the cluster directory being used by a Postgres server, from the server itself -- i.e. the service, (under Windows) was started by something like:

```
C:\foo\postgres.exe -D "D:\emr\data"
```

Is there a `SELECT` query or function one can make to the running server to retrieve the value `D:\emr\data`?

Answer (score 12):

(For completeness)
And even shorter:

```
SHOW data_directory;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'data_directory'
```